# Add IP to Inbound Rule Firewall Windows by ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, firewall

How to run firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=\"RuleName\" new remoteip=
```

from a middleware cmd?

They require "Admin Right" to run it, in context: ASP.NET Core 2.1 reactJs template.

I also tried to add "runas", and cmd start with '/c'

Add ip to rule in firewall